# Search entries by matrix field

Tags: matrix, categories

I have a matrix inside of which I have 2 fields, 1. dropdown list containing download types and another asset field. I would like to search first by a category and then I would like to further filter them and see if they have downloads of a certain type.

I would like to avoid a 2 step searching if possible and search articles that belong to certain category that have a certain download type associated with it.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the Matrix field on every entry save using the awesome Preparse plugin, to store the categories an entry contains in a new field.

https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft

Here’s example code for your Preparse field, it would store strings like `firstCategory,thirdCategory,secondCategory`.

```
{%- set categories = [] %}

{%- for block in entry.myMatrixField.type('myRelevantBlockType') %}
    {%- if block.myDropdownField %}
        {%- set categories = categories|merge([ block.myDropdownField.value ]) %}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}

{{- categories|join(',') -}}
```

Once you have populated that field for all your entries, you can filter them by a category using this criteria model.

```
{% set categoryToSearch = 'secondCategory' %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'myEntriesSection',
    search: 'myPreparseFieldHandle:*' ~ categoryToSearch ~ '*',
}) %}
```

I have to say that I’m not very proud of this solution as it uses `search` which I usually try to avoid. But I wasn’t able to come up with a better idea.

Comment: How would this work with existing imported content? I have imported over 65K + entries and about 7K entries need that.

Comment: Disable `devMode`, then go to Settings > Section > My Section where you click "Save" (you don’t have to edit any section settings). This should trigger a "Re-save Elements" task which should update all Preparse fields as well. 65K entries will take a while!

Comment: Thanks @carlcs I am going to give it a try and hopefully, it takes care of this easily

Comment: I haven't really worked on onSave events, can you expand on it? Also sorry been busy with other stuff so craft was on backburner. I am looking at ParseFieldPlugin.php. Do I assign categories | join(',') to new text field?

Comment: So I am not sure what I did wrong. I installed the plugin, created a field of that type, added it to my section, added the code you as an example and saved it. The field doesn't have any value. Is there a way to debug and see if what I did was right or wrong? Also ignore my previous comment