# Search on entries by Multi-Select field

Tags: search

I saw a [potentially similar question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/search-entries-by-matrix-field), but I'm wondering if mine is simpler.

I need to search for entries based on a match of a Multi-Select field. So, say if a user has a Tier of "TB" and an entry has a Muli-Select value of the options TB,B,P then the entry should be found. Likewise for an entry with the options G,A,P should not be found.

Here's my query at the moment

```
{% set query = 'eventRegion::"' ~ currentUser.userPabRegion ~ '" eventTier:"' ~ currentUser.userPabTier ~ '"' %}

{% paginate craft.entries.search( query ).sectionId( module.eventsModuleChannel ) as events %}
```

Comment: So I've managed to find a way to do it using the Preparse plugin (https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) but still interested to see if there's a native way.